# Why does a large white space appear in two column email signature in iPhone 6s, 7, and 8 between the image and the contact info?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, email, html-email

I'm trying to make a gmail signature. When I run the code through Litmus, it shows there is a large gap on iphone 6s, 7 and 8 between the image and the contact info on the right. How do I correct the layout in this email client? It appears right in every other client tested. Here is the code:

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Kendra Doss HTML Signature</title>
    
 <style type="text/css">
         /* Client-Specific styles */
         #outlook a   { padding:0; } /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" menu link. */
         body     { width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0; border:0; }
   
         /* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes, while not breaking desktop design. */
         .ExternalClass  { width:100%; } /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
         .ExternalClass,
   .ExternalClass p,
   .ExternalClass span,
   .ExternalClass font,
   .ExternalClass td,
   .ExternalClass div { line-height:100%; } /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing.*/
         img     { outline:none; text-decoration:none;border:none; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; }
         a img     { border:none; text-decoration:none;border:none; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; }
         p      { margin:0px 0px !important; }
         table     { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; }
         table td    { border-collapse:collapse; }
    
         /* iPad Styles */
         @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
             a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {
     text-decoration:none;
     color:#000000;
     pointer-events:none;
     cursor:default;
             }
             .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
     text-decoration:default;
     color:#000000 !important;
     pointer-events:auto;
     cursor:default;
             }
         }
         
         /* iPhone Styles */
         @media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {
             a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {
     text-decoration:none;
     color:#000000;
     pointer-events:none;
     cursor:default;
             }
             .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
     text-decoration:default;
     color:#000000 !important; 
     pointer-events:auto;
     cursor:default;
             }
         }
   
   /* Responsive styles */
     @media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {
      td[class=wrapper] {
       padding-top:0 !important;
       padding-left:0 !important;
       padding-right:0 !important;
      }
   
   table[class=mobile-view], td[class=mobile-view], img[class=mobile-view] {
       width:300px !important; 
       height:auto !important;    
      }
   
      td[class=clump] {
       display:block !important;
       padding-left:0 !important;
       padding-right:0 !important;
    width:100% !important;
      }
   
      td[class=aligncenter] {
       width:340px !important; 
       height:auto !important;
       text-align:center !important;
      }
     }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<table width="340" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-view" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
            <td width="100" valign="top" align="left" class="clump" style="padding:0 0 0px; 0;">
             <!-- Add your Avatar -->
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/BMWqfVH.jpg" alt="Kendra Doss" border="0" width="100" style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px; display:block; border:0; outline:0;" />
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="left" class="clump" style="padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td td width="240" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;">
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- Edit your Name or Title -->
                                        <td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px; line-height:24px; font-weight:800; text-transform:uppercase; color:#e34346; letter-spacing:1px;">Kendraa Doss</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- Edit your job title or subtitle -->
                                        <td height="15" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height:18px; font-weight:400; color:#6e7482; letter-spacing:1px;">UX &amp; Visual Designer</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           
                            <td style="padding:0 0 0 10px;">
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr><td height="2" style="padding:0 0 0 10px; font-size: 2px; line-height: 2px; border-bottom: 1px solid #daddee;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="60%" class="clump">
                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width="25" height="30" valign="middle"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZoPNmPa.png" alt="Phone" border="0" width="18" style="display:block; border:0; outline:none; padding:5px 0 0 0;" /></td>
                                                            <!-- Edit your Phone number -->
                                                            <td width="" height="30" valign="middle" align="left" style="padding:5px 0 0 0; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:24px; font-weight:400; color:#2f3542;"> 719.216.3402</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        
       <tr>
                            <td style="padding:0 0 0 10px;">
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                           
                                            
                                            <td width="33%" class="clump">
                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width="25" height="20" valign="middle"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/hnMRswj.png" alt="Web" border="0" width="18" style="display:block; border:0; outline:none;" /></td>
                                                            <!-- Edit your website URL -->
                                                            <td width="" height="20" valign="middle" align="left" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:24px; font-weight:400; color:#2f3542;"><a href="http://www.kendradoss.com" style="text-decoration:none; color:#2f3542;">kendradoss.com</a></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Attached is also screenshots from Litmus of how it appears in iPhone [Litmus screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8PCJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the need to clean the code up a little bit since there is any reference to external plugins. After that I tested your code in IPhone 5, 6, 6plus (can't test it on 7 yet), IPad, and Galaxy S5 and couldn't find any issue.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
<html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Kendra Doss HTML Signature</title>
  <head>

    <style type="text/css">
         /* Client-Specific styles */
         #outlook a         { padding:0; } /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" menu link. */
         body               { width:100% ; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0; border:0; }

         /* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes, while not breaking desktop design. */
         .ExternalClass     { width:100%; } /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
         .ExternalClass,
         .ExternalClass p,
         .ExternalClass span,
         .ExternalClass font,
         .ExternalClass td,
         .ExternalClass div { line-height:100%; } /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing.*/
         img                { outline:none; text-decoration:none;border:none; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; }
         a img              { border:none; text-decoration:none;border:none; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; }
         p                  { margin:0px 0px ; }
         table              { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; }
         table td           { border-collapse:collapse; }

         /* iPad Styles */
         @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
             a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {
                 text-decoration:none;
                 color:#000000;
                 pointer-events:none;
                 cursor:default;
             }
             .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
                 text-decoration:default;
                 color:#000000 ;
                 pointer-events:auto;
                 cursor:default;
             }
         }

         /* iPhone Styles */
         @media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {
             a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {
                 text-decoration:none;
                 color:#000000;
                 pointer-events:none;
                 cursor:default;
             }
             .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
                 text-decoration:default;
                 color:#000000 ; 
                 pointer-events:auto;
                 cursor:default;
             }
         }

         /* Responsive styles */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {
            td[class=wrapper] {
                padding-top:0 ;
                padding-left:0 ;
                padding-right:0 ;
            }

            table[class=mobile-view], td[class=mobile-view], img[class=mobile-view] {
                width:300px ;   
                height:auto ;    
            }

            td[class=clump] {
                display:block ;
                padding-left:0 ;
                padding-right:0 ;
                width:100% ;
            }

            td[class=aligncenter] {
                width:340px ;   
                height:auto ;
                text-align:center ;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<table width="340" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-view">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="left"  style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px; display:block; border:0; outline:0;">
                <!-- Add your Avatar -->
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/BMWqfVH.jpg" alt="Kendra Doss" border="0" width="100" />
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="left" style="padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td td width="240" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;">
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- Edit your Name or Title -->
                                        <td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px; line-height:24px; font-weight:800; text-transform:uppercase; color:#e34346; letter-spacing:1px;">Kendraa Doss</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- Edit your job title or subtitle -->
                                        <td height="15" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height:18px; font-weight:400; color:#6e7482; letter-spacing:1px;">UX &amp; Visual Designer</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding:0 0 0 10px;">
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr><td height="2" style="padding:0 0 0 10px; font-size: 2px; line-height: 2px; border-bottom: 1px solid #daddee;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="60%" class="clump">
                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width="25" height="30" valign="middle"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZoPNmPa.png" alt="Phone" border="0" width="18" style="display:block; border:0; outline:none; padding:5px 0 0 0;" /></td>
                                                            <!-- Edit your Phone number -->
                                                            <td width="" height="30" valign="middle" align="left" style="padding:5px 0 0 0; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:24px; font-weight:400; color:#2f3542;"> 719.216.3402</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td style="padding:0 0 0 10px;">
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="33%" class="clump">
                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width="25" height="20" valign="middle"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/hnMRswj.png" alt="Web" border="0" width="18" style="display:block; border:0; outline:none;" /></td>
                                                            <!-- Edit your website URL -->
                                                            <td width="" height="20" valign="middle" align="left" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:24px; font-weight:400; color:#2f3542;"><a href="http://www.kendradoss.com" style="text-decoration:none; color:#2f3542;">kendradoss.com</a></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. Do not user "!important" if you doesn't mean it. Improper use could overlap styles making problem solving a living hell.

Answer (score 0):

It might be to do with the width set to 100% in CSS

```
td[class=clump] {
    display:block !important;
    padding-left:0 !important;
    padding-right:0 !important;
    width:100% !important;
}
```

set it to:

```
td[class=clump] {
    display:block !important;
    padding-left:0 !important;
    padding-right:0 !important;
    width:auto !important;
}
```

It should fix the spacing issues.