# HTML email signature issues

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, signature

Developers and enthusiasts!

Since I have a little experience with HTML I figured it would be fun to try to create an html email signature, and it was! Until I checked the result on Litmus. So many tiny flaws I can not figure out how to fix:

• personal information appears partly or completely under the logo in Outlook on PC, instead of next to the logo.

• social media icons not visible in Apple mail, only before sending.

• correct space between social media icons in browsers, iPad mail and iPhone mail but not in Outlook on PC (or when running the code on here).

Are these compatibility problems that can not be fixed?
If they can, I need your help!

[This is how the signature is supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J75YF.png) (the logo is an animation).

And this is the code:

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      
       <p style="line-height: 11px; padding: 0px; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 12px;">
      
      <a href="http://www.joramipsum.com" target="_blank" ><img src="https://joramipsum.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/email_animatie-7.gif" width=116 border="0" style="float: left; padding: 0 15px 0 0;" alt="IPSUM logo" title="click for portfolio, testimonials and free consult!"> </a>
        
      <a style="font-style: bold; color: #333333;"><strong>Joram Esveld</strong></a><br>
       
        <a style="line-height: 18px; color: #017d85">branding specialist</a>
        <br><br>
      
        <a href="https://www.joramipsum.com/" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#017d85'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#333333'" target="_blank"
        style="text-decoration: none; color:#333333;" >www.joramipsum.com</a><br>
        
        <a href="tel:+31612345678" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#017d85'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#333333'" target="_blank" style="line-height: 18px; text-decoration: none; color: #333333;">+316 12 34 56 78</a><br><br>
     
       <a href="https://www.facebook.com/joramipsum" target="_blank" ><img src="https://joramipsum.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/facebook.png" width=24 border="0" style="float: left; padding: 0 3 0 0;" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook"> </a>
        
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/joramipsum" target="_blank" ><img src="https://joramipsum.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/instagram.png" width=24 border="0" style="float: left; padding: 0 3 0 0;" alt="Instagram" title="Instagram"> </a>
        
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com/joramipsum" target="_blank" ><img src="https://joramipsum.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/twitter.png" width=24 border="0" style="float: left; padding: 0 3 0 0;" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter"> </a>
        
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/joramipsum" target="_blank" ><img src="https://joramipsum.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/linkedin.png" width=24 border="0" style="float: left; padding: 0 3 0 0;" alt="LinkedIn" title="LinkedIn"> </a>
     </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Let me know if you need more information.
And if anyone has any branding related questions; 
feel free to ask thrue dm, or my website.

Kind regards,
Joram

Comment: [This is how your html code should look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46698653/why-does-a-large-white-space-appear-in-two-column-email-signature-in-iphone-6s). Use tables for columns, stay away from forms and JavaScript. Both of these can cause your email to land in spam folders.

Answer (score 0):

`JavaScript` will not work in an email client.

Outlook ignores `padding` on images.

`float` mostly does not work with Outlook.

A better approach would be to divide the signature into two separate columns using `td`.

For more information on what works with email, try this handy source:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Gwally I removed the `javascript` and used the code added by u/Syfer to fix the `padding` and `float` issues. Cheated a bit with the padding of the social media icons by giving the images some transparant room on the side, but it works good enough.